# C# Reading data from Rocksmith's Realtone Cable

Tags: c#, .net, usb

I have a bit of an unorthodox question. I am trying to do a little pet project purely out of interest and willingness to mess around for fun and giggles.

I want to read data (bytes, bits or whatever I can) from my rocksmith cable(usb cable attached to a guitar), and just go whack at it in some c# code. I actually have no idea if this is even possible. I have been playing around with libraries such as SharpUsb and LibUsbDotNet, but they don't seem to pick it up as a device, which kindof makes sense.

I also tried using System.IO.Ports.SerialPort, just to see if I can pick up anything but it does not.

So smarter genius people out there. Is this possible ? Any advice/ideas of what I can try ?

Any advice or ideas will be very much appreciated! For me this is purely an out of interest project for fun.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it is used as a MIDI input you could use a c# MIDI-Lib there are a few of them

Answer (score 0):

Since the rocksmith Realtone cable is a usb to guitar cable, all you should need the dll file for that piece of hardware and import it into your project / call the proper methods associated with it. 
More than likely the code will be in C++, so you will need to use DLLImport function as well. 
Any further than that, I'm sure you could figure out where to go from there. You could possibly use XNA and use the microphone class if you have that usb device set as your default microphone, although, that is just a random thought.